# Se creashea mi emulador de android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, rest

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto que me pasaron, es una aplicación que constantemente hace consultas REST, ya sea por que el usuario presiona un botón o por que llega la hora de realizar una petición.
El problema es que cuando el backend al que la aplicación hace las consultas presenta fallos, en mi emulador la aplicación tiende a cerrarse y crashearse por completo como se muestra en la imagen de abajo, estos cierres pueden ser aleatorios, no solamente cuando el usuario presiona un botón para comenzar la consulta. Ya revisé el logcat y ahí no me marca alguna excepción o error ¿Me podrían ayudar con sugerencias de que podría hacer para encontrar el fallo?

[image: Cresheo del emulador cuando el backend presenta fallas]

Comment: ¿Algún Log disponible?

Answer (score -1):

Lo primero que debes hacer es lanzar el servicio de backend con un Postman(u otro programa) y ver la respuesta que te devuelve.

Esto te ayudará a saber si estás poniendo bien la URL, credenciales y si lleva algún tipo de header... la idea es que repliques la llamada que haces y con la cual tengas mayor control.

Ahora pasan 2 cosas.

1º - Si el servicio te devuelve un 400-500 en cualquiera de sus escalas, a ti te saldrá directamente por error y si lo tienes controlado, te saldrá un log.

2º - Como no te sale el log, el problema está en el mapeo de los datos que has hecho, te has equivocado al escribir. es decir el servidor te está devolviendo

Ejemplo:
`{'nombre':'user'}`

Y en tu clase Java lo has mapeado como

```
public class Persona {
private String nonbre;
```

Además, necesitas los @getters,@setters y el constructor vacío y el constructor con todos los parámetros...

Si lo que quieres es comprobar que esto es cierto, en vez de recoger la respuesta del servidor como una clase Java, recógela como un String e imprímelo, si te imprime el resultado, es por algo mencionado en el punto 2.

Cuando tengas logs o algo, será más fácil ayudarte.